# wait for all http request to finish in Angular

Tags: angular

im new to Angular. My school project is to make a web app with an API.
My problem is that from the API I can get characters no problem, but the characters have fields (father, mother, spouse, ...) witch are strings or string arrays. If these are known, the strings are urls for the api (.../api/character/34 for example) but if unknown these are empty strings.

I want a function where I can give it a string array as input(these strings are urls from the api), the function iterates the array and get all the characters from the api, and when everybody joins the party it calls a subject.next, so I can know for sure that the data arrived where I need it.

I read about is in other posts, but for example the forkJoint seems to be deprecated in vscode.
I'm curious what's the best practice currently, but any working "good-enough" code will make my day happy

Thanks in advance

EDIT:
The api i use is the Ice and Fire api, https://anapioficeandfire.com/

my codes currently look like this:

I have the function which communicate with the api:

```
getDataByURL(url: string) {
        return this.http
            .get(
                url, { observe: 'response' }
            )
    }
```

currently I have a pretty sad solution which looks like this:

```
fillCharacterConnections(id: number) {
        let char = this.characters[id];

        if(char.father) {
            this.apiHandler.getDataByURL(char.father).subscribe(father => {
                this.currentCharacterFather = this.constructCharacter(father.body as Character);
                this.characterConnectionsFather.next();
    
            })
        }
        
        if(char.mother) {
            this.apiHandler.getDataByURL(char.mother).subscribe(mother => {
                this.currentCharacterMother = this.constructCharacter(mother.body as Character);
                this.characterConnectionsmother.next();
            })
        }
        
        if(char.spouse) {
            this.apiHandler.getDataByURL(char.spouse).subscribe(spouse => {
                this.currentCharacterSpouse = this.constructCharacter(spouse.body as Character)
                this.characterConnectionsSpouse.next();
            })
        }
        
    }
```

This solution *works* but there must be a better way. Especially because I want something reuseable.

Comment: Can you share your code please for more Explanation!

Comment: `forkJoin` is not deprecated